# Jump between cases in C switch statements

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have the following code to define my FSM states:

```
enum states
{
    START,              // Send request to remote IP or wait for a request (WAIT_CONN_REQ)
    WAIT_RESP,          // Chat request sent to remote IP. Waiting for a response from the target machine
    SEND_CONN_RESP,     // Chat request received from remote IP. ACCEPT or REJECT
    ACCEPTED            // Both parties agreed to exchange datagrams. Begin application data (MESSAGES) exchange
};
typedef enum states states;
states state;
```

My thought process was this: My chat program will have the aforementioned four states. What's the best way to do this neatly? Using a switch statement, of course. So how can I do it? Like this: (code is simplified & replaced with `printf` functions"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    state = START;
    switch (state)
    {
        case START:
            printf("Simple Chat Client - START state\n");
            if (argv[1] != NULL)
            {
                SEND_CONN_REQ();
                } else {
                WAIT_CONN_REQ();
            }
            break;
        case WAIT_RESP:
            printf("WAIT_RESP STATE!");
            break;
        case SEND_CONN_RESP:
            printf("SEND_CONN_RESP state!");
            break;
        case ACCEPTED:
            printf("ACCEPTED state!");
            break;
    }
}
```

But this does not do what I want. I want it to jump to another case when a condition is met. Like so:

```
    if (argv[1] != NULL)
                    {
                        SEND_CONN_REQ();
                        goto case WAIT_RESP;          
                        } else {
                        WAIT_CONN_REQ();
                    }
                    break;
                case WAIT_RESP:
                    printf("WAIT_RESP STATE!");
                    break;
```

My logic tells me that the way to do this would be to change the `state` variable, assuming the whole `switch` would be executed again with the new variable. But what happens is that I have to either use `break` and quit the `switch`, or not use it and let the program execute the next `case`.

So I looked at other options, like `do` statements and `continue`. But everywhere I look, using `case` seems to be the way to go with an FSM.

I would appreciate any help on how to do this properly. Is a `switch` statement even the best way to go?

Comment: Your switch statement is mute. Any please do not use goto

Comment: @EdHeal Hey Ed! - I know `goto` is bad and should never be used, I only put it there so I could convey what I meant. But thank you for your advice! Could you please explain what "mute" means?

Comment: You set `state` then use it in the `switch` statement. i.e. If is a forgone conclusion as to the route it will go. Also it is in the `main` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to code a state machine like that is using a loop and a switch:

```
state = START;
while (state != STOP)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case START:
            printf("Simple Chat Client - START state\n");
            if (argv[1] != NULL)
            {
                SEND_CONN_REQ();
            } else {
                WAIT_CONN_REQ();
            }
            break;
        case WAIT_RESP:
            printf("WAIT_RESP STATE!");
            break;
        case SEND_CONN_RESP:
            printf("SEND_CONN_RESP state!");
            break;
        case ACCEPTED:
            printf("ACCEPTED state!");
            break;
    }
}
```

Each action can optionally set the new state so that the next iteration will do the appropriate actions.  Don't forget to output newlines at the ends of `printf()` statements if you want to see the output in a timely manner.  It may not matter on Windows; it does on other platforms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer - Hello - It is in the main function and also just before the switch  the value is set

Comment: The `state` is set to `START` in the `main()` in the question, but it is never altered after that.  I've not written the correct alterations into my outline code; I don't know for sure what they are.  But any time the code goes around the loop, something should set `state` to the correct next value, so that the correct activity goes on in the next iteration.  When the code is done, it sets `state` to the (hypothetical) STOP state so that the loop terminates.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hello - Thank you for this! This seems very neat. I know you said this is the normal way to code a state machine, but could you explain why this code is better than the one unexpected62 posted?

Comment: I don't think I can edit posts yet - if the answer to my question is "because it doesn't use goto" you can ignore it.

Comment: It's not so much that it doesn't use `goto` as that it allows you to have code that determines the next event which in turn drives the transition to the next state, etc.  The `goto` can be considered a version of the `while` statement (a little charitably).  If you have a very simple state machine, you may not need the loop/switch construct.  For very complex state machines, you may end up with quite complex structures and lots of pointers to functions.  See also the [State Machine Compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) for more information.

Comment: But isn't `goto` just faster sometimes? I have a state machine that gets a handle and checks some conditions on start of each step. But I have a situation: if nothing do to in step 1 then go to step 2. It even matches its description in English. I wish there was another keyword like "skip" to... skip to the next case. For now I stick to `goto`. It saves some CPU cycles. BTW, the overall state doesn't change between steps 1 and 2. So the `goto` is my obvious choice.

Comment: @Harry: If `goto` fits your needs, use it.  But be cautious.  Using `goto` can easily (but not necessarily) lead to logic that is very contorted and difficult to follow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My `goto` uses counter is currently 2 ;) For the C language. In C# I used it for "try/catch" error handlers, when the user had the "Retry" option. If I had to add it to my `goto` counter, I would treat it as one, though it's in several places. My last `goto` went at the end of a state machine that needs to restart the process, but skipping some initialization is highly beneficial. I treat `goto` as `cut corners` optimization. In C# try/catch it made code simpler, in my C driver it just makes it a bit easier on CPU. So 3 `gotos` for like 1M LOC ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you will always just want to execute the state right below where you are, you could remove the `break` statement. I would put a comment in it's place like `/* fall through */` so that it is clear that it is intentionally missing for people who follow, as well as your future-forgetting self. I personally don't like this method.

Why not change the `state` variable, and then just execute a `goto` that is right above the switch statement? Like this maybe:

```
switchStart:
    switch (state)
    {
        case START:
            printf("Simple Chat Client - START state\n");
            if (argv[1] != NULL)
            {
                SEND_CONN_REQ();
                state = STATE_HERE; // change your state
                goto switchStart; // jump to the top of the switch
                } else {
                WAIT_CONN_REQ();
            }
            break;
        case WAIT_RESP:
            printf("WAIT_RESP STATE!");
            break;
        case SEND_CONN_RESP:
            printf("SEND_CONN_RESP state!");
            break;
        case ACCEPTED:
            printf("ACCEPTED state!");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Hey! This works perfectly! Thank you! What's the "gotcha"? Or is there one at all? This seems so simple and does exactly what I need.

Comment: The "gotcha" is that people typically like to stay away from "goto" statements, as it can make reading code and debugging difficult sometimes. I don't particularly like them either, but since you brought up a goto, I figured you weren't opposed to the idea. :-D. Thanks for accepting the answer. Please upvote as well if you think it is well written.

Comment: Well, when you put it that way... I don't think using `goto` is a good practice for a beginner. I put it there so people could understand what I wanted to achieve - or rather I could explain it better. I don't think I will be using this solution, even though it seems like the simplest way. But thank you for your answer, it is much appreciated! (I can't upvote posts yet)